# Write file with int[10] without ‘ ’ or ‘\n’, When I read it, there is something wrong?

Tags: c++, c, fopen, fread, printf

```
#define MAXN 1000000
FILE *fp1;
fp1 = fopen("num.txt", "w");
for(int i=0; i<MAXN; i++) {
    int a = rand() % (MAXN/10);
    fprintf(fp1, "%d", a);
}
...
FILE *fp2;
fp2 = fopen("num.txt", "r");
int a;
fscanf(fp2, "%d", &a);
printf("%d", a);
```

when I create a file, and fopen it to fp.

and I read it with fread, and I got the wrong num

(such as the first num 6414, and I got num -1182340738)

And I write it with '\n' or ' ' there is no error.

Comment: I don't see the code you use for reading.

Comment: oh, sorry? But I can see it in page...

Comment: for(int i=0; i<MAXN; i++) {
    int a = rand() % (MAXN/10);
    fprintf(fp, "%d", a);
}   //there it is, sorry for my first question here.

Comment: Just to be clear, `fprintf()` does a write.  I would expect some other code does a read.

Comment: Since you don't test if the file opened properly for reading and I don't see any code that closes the file after writing I'd guess you left it open and the second open failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a character separating the numbers, how does your parser know when one number ends and the next starts?

This I guess is your problem, it's thinking it's one very big number and overflowing to negative.

Comment: Does it mean that when I write int on and on, the num of int is not separated by 4bytes?

Comment: Correct. You're writing the number as an ASCII string with no separator between items. If you want to write the raw bytes, you should be using `fwrite` instead of `fprintf` - e.g. `fwrite(&a, sizeof(int), 1, fp);`.

Answer (score 0):

If your add `\n`,the file buffer will flush,but without `\n` it will not flush,
so you should close first fp1 before you open the fp2.